# PredicateBuilder and nested predicates

Tags: linq-to-sql, predicatebuilder

I'm trying to use the Predicate from [Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) to create a TSQL statement like:

```
select * from channel
where channel.VendorID IN (@vendorIDs)
AND channel.FranchiseID IN (@franchiseIDs)
```

or a predicate like : c => (c.VendorID = x || c.VendorID == x2 ...) && (c.FranchiseID == f || c.FranchiseID == f2 ...)

but I'm having troubles. Here is my attempt:

```
    var vendorPredicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Channel>();
    foreach (Vendor vendor in workOrderSessionData.SelectedVendors)
    {
        int tempId = vendor.VendorID;
        vendorPredicate = vendorPredicate.Or(c => c.VendorID == tempId);
    }

    var franchisePredicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Channel>();
    foreach (Franchise franchise in workOrderSessionData.SelectedFranchises)
    {
        int tempId = franchise.FranchiseID;
        franchisePredicate = franchisePredicate.Or(c => c.FranchiseID == tempId);
        // doesn't work franchisePredicate.Or(vendorPredicate);
    }

Channel.SelectByPredicate(franchisePredicate);
```

My table has 60,000 rows, so going to the database and selecting them all, then filtering is not an option. Channel is a LinqToSql entity. Also either the SelectedFranchises or the SelectedVendors can be empty, but not both at one time.
EDIT: I need to distinct this list by the channel.Franchise.Name as well.. Maybe I should just use a stored procedure?

How would you do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To side step the whole predicate issue why not use the "Contains()" statement?

IE

```
var myResults =
    from c in Channel
    where
        workOrderSessionData.SelectedVendors.Select(sv => 
            sv.VendorID).Contains(c.VendorID)

        && workOrderSessionData.SelectedFranchises.Select(sf => 
            sf.FranchiseID).Contains(c.FranchiseID)
    select c;
Channel.SelectByPredicate(franchisePredicate);
```

Alternatively, to use the predicate method, you wouldn't want to join them with an "or" because the two conditions are "and"'d in your example SQL statement.  Instead, just run them consecutively through a where clause.  I don't know how your SelectByPredicate function works, but you may be successful following the same pattern with it:

```
var myResults = Channel.SelectByPredicate(franchisePredicate);
myResults = myResults.SelectByPredicate(vendorPredicate);

var myResults = Channel.Where(franchisePredicate).Where(vendorPredicate);
```

**Update From Discussion in Comments**

If what you want is to only match on vendor id/franchise id if the workordersessiondata contains at least one of those ids, you'd use the following logic:

```
List<int> VendorIDs = workOrderSessionData.SelectedVendors.Select(sv => 
    sv.VendorID).ToList();

List<int> FranchiseIDs = workOrderSessionData.SelectedFranchises.Select(sf => 
    sf.FranchiseID).ToList();

var myResults = Channel;

if(VendorIDs.Count > 0)
    myResults = MyResults.Where(c => VendorIDs.Contains(c.VendorID));

if(FranchiseIDs.Count > 0)
    myResults = MyResults.Where(c => FranchiseIDs.Contains(c.FranchiseID));
```

Comment: the first example fails if the SelectedVendors is empty or the SelectedFranchises is empty (which is possible). How would you handle that? The where clause from the Sql Profilier is "WHERE 0 = 1"

Comment: By fails do you mean it returns 0 rows or it throws an exception?

Comment: by fails I mean an empty result from the database. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Not a problem.  The reason I ask is that the SQL query you provided would also return no results if either of those IN statements fail because its saying that the both IDs must be in their respective lists.  It sounds like you're asking for that except in cases where one of the lists is empty, then you only want to match the full list.  Is that right?

Comment: When one of the lists is empty, I still need to filter based on the other list that is populated. So I need to get all channels by the vendors and the franchises or all channels for the vendors or all channels for the franchises.

Answer (score 0):

Well I just did this:

```
var prope = outerWhere.ToString();
if (prope.Equals("f => True") == false || prope.Equals("f => False") == false)
  query = query.Where(outerWhere);
```

Maybe tho the cleanest of all versions...

Answer (score 0):

Given the extensions:

```
public static class PredicateExtensions
{
    public static Predicate<T> Or<T>(this Predicate<T> @this, Predicate<T> or) {
        return value => @this(value) || or(value);
    }

    public static Predicate<T> And<T>(this Predicate<T> @this, Predicate<T> and) {
        return value => @this(value) && and(value);
    }
}
```

You could do this:

```
    Predicate<Channel> vendorPredicate = c => false;

    foreach (var vendor in workOrderSessionData.SelectedVendors)
    {
        int tempId = vendor.VendorID;       
        vendorPredicate = vendorPredicate.Or(c => c.VendorID == tempId);
    }

    Predicate<Channel> franchisePredicate = c => false;
    foreach (var franchise in workOrderSessionData.SelectedFranchises)
    {
        int tempid = franchise.FranchiseID;
        franchisePredicate = franchisePredicate.Or(c => c.FranchiseID == tempid);
    }

    var channelPredicate = vendorPredicate.And(franchisePredicate);

    var query = Channels.Where (c => channelPredicate(c));
}
```